# How to assign a default category to new registered user in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use `woo-commerce` plugin in my site, there i use `WooCommerce Restrict Categories Plus` plugin for restrict the categories and their products to users, it works perfectly.

Now i noticed that when i create a new user,  there is no category assigned to it, automatically, all categories assign to it by default. I want a plugin or any `woo-commerce` hook so when i create a new user a default category, which i set, assign to a new user. I searched for it, but nothing get.

Please help me soon as possible, how can i do this, or is this possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting in your admin pane under `Settings>General` called `New User Default Role`. Is that what you are looking for?

More info can be found here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Comment: thanx thanx alot bro, you solved my problem, i got an idea from this and it solved my problem